# Phantom first entry in horizontal list

Tags: css, html, css-float, html-lists

I am adjusting the spacing in a horizontal list and it seems I have a blank first entry generating a seperator (border-right).  Increasing and decreasing the padding, expands and shrinks the first phantom entry in the list.

The nav bar on this page http://compuball.com/GW2/guides/ranger/pages/pet_basics_101.html

The spacer bars are created to the right of the menu items ... the first spacer is following an item that isn't supposed to exist.

The css:

```
NAV {
    width: 940px;
    float: left;
    font-family: Geneva,Arial;
    border: 6px outset #A96505;
    background-color: #F4CB90;
}

NAV ul {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

NAV li {
    display: inline;
}

NAV li a {
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 2px groove #C6995F;
    font-size: 1.6em; 
    padding: 2px 10px;
    color: #A96505;
    text-decoration: none;
}

NAV li a.last {
    border-right: none;
}

NAV li a:hover {
    color: #6D3F02;
}
```

The HTML:

```
    <NAV>
        <UL>
            <LI><a href="#top">Home</a></LI>
            <LI><a href="#Intro">Introduction</a></LI>
            <LI><a href="#Charming">Acquiring Pets</a></LI>
            <LI><a href="#Classification">Classification</a></LI>
            <LI><a href="#Control">Control Panel</a></LI>
            <LI><a Class="last" href="#Management">Management Panel</a></LI>
        </UL>
    </NAV>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem. The first spacer (for me in Chromium 6) is after Home where it should be. So which browser are you using? Nice design and gfx by the way. Other than the ugly yellow footer of course :-)

Comment: why are there four `a` tags with the same `id` (top)?

Comment: Not sure why others are seeing four tags.  I deleted the server files and replaced them.  I am using Firefox 16, and in IE9 the problem did not exist.  The page was "magnified by a factor of about 4 and there was no formatting since the content was wider than the browser window.  Also the NAV bar had a double top border.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this:

```
<HEAD>
  <A ID = "top" />
</HEAD>
```

What you want to do is move this out of the `<head>` of your document, and move it right after the `<body>` tag. Also, given the excellent comments below, we should make it look something like this, as `<a>` tags aren't self-closing:

```
<a id="top"></a>
```

Comment: Moved it to the body.  And changed the A ID tags that had the same names as my ARTICLE classes.  It didn't solve the problem, but you were right and I thought I should clean it up.

Comment: I took out the "a" and just had a naked ID="top", then removed the previous fix of (nav a[id="top"] { display: none; }).  It worked fine.  I am obviously clueless about bookmarks in css.  It appears a naked ID will act as a bookmark when referenced by a link to the ID.  In the old HTML, the # was required to create a bookmark ... or my mind just had it implanted from the past.  Thank you.

Comment: You want to move the entire tag, `<a id='top'></a>`, to be within the `<body>` of your document.

Comment: Good point, Rick. Fixed the comment. The point of the matter remains though, that it sounded like this guy took my answer at face value and just deleted the 'a'.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, there is a definate problem here - when looked at in FireBug, you have four instances `<a id="top">` before you even get to your Wrapper section. One of these is within your navigation list, creating an element (which then gets padded, etc.).

I'm guessing you want an internal link, enabling users to get to the top of the page without scrolling. This involves **one** target reference at the top of the page (not within your navigation list) like so: `<a name="top"></a>` and as many corresponding links down the page as you need, like so: `<a href="#top">Back to Top<a>`. That will bring the top of the screen back to the point on the page where the target reference lies.

So. Clean out all intances of `<a id="top"></a>` and replace them with one proper target reference at the top of the page (just after the opening `<body>` tag, for example) and you should be fine.

Comment: +1 for your answer. It is the preferred way to do it. I do just want to mention to the question poster that if for some reason you can't modify the code to remove the element, you can address your issue with this css rule: nav a[id="top"] { display: none; }. However, the best solution is to remove the <a id="top"></a> in the first pace, since an id is only supposed to appear once on the page.

Comment: My css only had on ID="top", and it was up in the header.  I don't see an instance of the ID="top" elsewhere.  I did ad nav a[id="top"] { display: none; } without seeing the problem and it did work.

Comment: This solution is useful in that it explains the correct usage of the links, but it fails to see what is causing this guy's problem. Cleaning out 'all instances' of that `a` is really just cleaning out one, which I pointed out in my solution.

Comment: @user1772849 hiding the anchor with CSS is not a proper long-term solution, although it may seem handy now. You should get into your HTML and clean out those instances of `<a id="top">` and, as noted in other comments, ensure that all subsequent anchors that you decide to leave in your code are properly closed with a `</a>` tag. Hiding that element via CSS could have repercussions on other elements in the page on various browsers, especially as you never closed off the link. Finally, the method I describe is the correct way for internal page bookmarks, not `<id="top">`!

Answer (score 1):

Your first li actually has two a tags in it one for  not sure how that is appearing given it doesn't show when you view source but it is there. In Chrome right click the home link and choose inspect element you'll see it listed there.

Are you hand typing this HTML or is something generating it for you?

Near the top of your page you have:

```
 <A ID = "top" />
```

a tags are not self closing, so what is happening is that tag isn't closing until it finds the first  which is in your menu, creating an extra element in the menu.

```
<a id="top"></a>
```

Will solve your issue with the extra menu item

Run your page through this: http://validator.w3.org to find other errors (you have surprisingly few of them! Well done!)

Comment: I openned my page in IE9 and there was no nav list problem, there was also no formatting for the page.  It appeared huge and filled the entire page from the left border to the right border.

Comment: Thank you.  I will never self close an <A> tag again, especially <A> tags that are absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: You're quite welcome, be nice if you accepted the answer as the correct one.